# Velocity Verlet Algorithm for rotational motion simulation

Tags: molecular-dynamics

I have to simulate a system of self propelled particles for which I have to use Langevin translational equation which is equation 1, (terms have there usual meaning) and I plug the forces calculated from equation 1 into velocity verlet algorithm.

But the rotational equation 2, I do not understand to how to simulate,

I want to ask, if there is any velocity verlet like algorithm for 2D rotational equation simulation in which I just supply the calculated Torque from the equation as we do velocity verlet?
Thanks

[image: Langevin Equation for translation and Rotation]

Comment: In molecular dynamis simulations, usually the particles are point-like, so there is no torque on a single particle. Is that different in your case?

Comment: Yes. I am having rod shaped particles(2D). Each rod is made up by connecting beads of some radius using springs , above eqn. and the dynamics is from the paper, https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.120.188002

Comment: So you want to apply an external torque to these particles? Or is the torque just the result of the interaction forces acting between the heads? In the first case (i think), you would just convert the torque to a force via the instantaneous distance between the heads, in the second case you would not need the second equation and just use only the first.

Comment: No external torque is used, rather because of all other forces(with wall forces including). This rotational equation is important,, I have already simulated without the second equation, the video looks fine, but the dynamics ain't produces the correct result, and looks like something Physics is missing, that I really don't know. Right now I am trying to solve the eq2 using verlet algo. in analogy to verlet for cartesian for eq1, which will give me theta and omega. And I guess dividing F in eq1 into components may work. Not sure. I am trying.

Comment: Is $r_i$ the center of your rods or the position of each head? Either, the situation is wierd... the equations are meant for fixed length rods, while you use flexible rods. Or, if $r_i$ is the position of each head, then the equations are wierd because there should be no torque in the equations, as the torque emerges as the result of the interactions between the heads.

Comment: btw. i can not find the equations you mention above in the paper

Comment: It's in the supplementary materials, of the paper where they have mentioned the simulation details,, Actually the rods are connected by a springs, and a bending force is also applied which gives the shape of rod, then the above Langevin dynamics governs it's motion,, where r_i is the position of each individual beads,, I added that in this link, kindly check,, https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Trxu6-87kL67EoKwTTqMGYOPtVv1hNQp

Comment: Ok. I am now pretty sure what is meant with the equations. First, the particles making up the rod are not connected by springs (at least I cant find any mention of this in the paper) but by rigid connections. That makes a seperate torque equation make sense.